# Problem with urllib

Tags: python, sockets, urllib

I wrote this code:

```
import urllib
proxies = {'http': 'http://112.65.135.54:8080/'}
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener(proxies)
r = opener.open("http://www.python.org/")
print r.read()
```

and when I execute it this program works fine, and send for me source code of python.org  But when i use this:

```
import urllib
proxies = {'http': 'http://80.176.245.196:1080/'}
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener(proxies)
r = opener.open("http://www.python.org/")
print r.read()
```

this program does not send me the source code of python.org 
What am I going to do?

Comment: Eva: I originally obfuscated the IP address thinking this might be private information. Unfortunately, I cannot tell based on the question if the IP address is essential to what you're asking. If it is not and the address has privacy issues, consider replacing it with something generic.

Comment: @Bob, it is of course quite essential (I could have discovered that the second one's a socks proxy, not an http one, if you hadn't masked them with your edit;-).  Fortunately, no harm done, as the OP came up with that key fact without my assistance... but there's no way "something generic" could have enabled anybody to divine that!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the first IP address and port points to a working proxy, while the second set does not (they're on private IPs so of course nobody else can check).  So, speak with whoever handles your local network, and get the exact specs for IP and port of the HTTP proxy you're supposed to use!

**Edit**: aargh, the question had been edited to "mask" the IPs (now they're back and they're definitely not on private networks!) -- so the answer was based on that.  Anyway, no need for digging now, as the OP has already discovered that one is a socks proxy, not an http proxy, and so of course can't be treated as the latter;-).

Answer (score 1):

hehe :d i find the answer i must use "socks" instead of "http" :
import urllib
proxies = {'socks': 'http://80.176.245.196:1080/'}
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener(proxies)
r = opener.open("http://www.python.org/")
print r.read()

this code works fine